# Get attribution to Appsflyer

Tags: flutter, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

I need to get de attributions from a short link(onelink) from AppsFlyer.
I tried to do https://dev.appsflyer.com/hc/reference/get-onelink-attribution-link, but always get 401 "Authentication Failed".